# VSTS Extension - Token authentication error

Tags: azure-devops

My team and I are working on creating a VSTS extension that will work with VSTS/Azure DevOps in the cloud, but the following 500 error is being thrown when trying to do a REST request:

```
HostAuthorizationNotFound
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.DelegatedAuthorization.SessionTokenCreateException
```

Here's the code:

```
// Get an instance of the client
var client = RestClient.getClient();
client.getWorkItem(10343, ["System.Title"]).then( 
    function(workItem) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(workItem))
    },
    function () {console.log("test")}
);
```

Uninstalling and reinstalling the extension has no effect, which seems to be the solution for others who have encountered this problem, and the extension scope was updated to include work items.

Additionally, the personal access token generated for my account works with the VSTS CLI.  I'm able to create and query for work items with no issues there.

The Microsoft documentations mentions manual token creation for programs such as C# console apps, but my impression is that this should not be needed when working with an extension.

Is there something token related that needs to be explicitly declared in code?

Answer (score 0):

The solution ended up being the same as what others have posted about:  uninstalling and reinstalling the extension.  In this case this was something that we tried initially but did not do entirely correctly -- the reinstallation did not take full effect since all the steps weren't followed (an admin also needed to approve the republishing of the extension).

So if you get this error, rest assured that uninstalling and reinstalling should do the trick!

See the following link for more details:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/get-started/node?view=vsts#install-your-extension